# Get size of input in console

Tags: c++

How would you get the size input string to console or size of valid characters in buffer?

```
char buffer[100];
cin >> buffer;
```

I'm looking to put the '\0' where the input ends.

Comment: Technically speaking, `cin' represents the console's input stream, which is not guaranteed to have an end, unless cin.eof() returns true. It's just like reading a file, except you don't know its size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is moot.  When the user types more than 100 characters, you have a buffer overrun.  You may crash.  If not, you got a security issue at best.  You shouldn't do this.  Read the input a character at a time, or use a safer string library.  gets_s comes to mind if it's supported on your platform.

But in answer to your question, this might be what you need:

```
char buffer[100] = {}; // zero-init the entire array
int length = 0;
cin >> buffer;
length = strlen(buffer); // length is the length of the string
```

Answer (score 9):

Prefer using `std::string`, instead of `char*` or `char[]`. That makes such things easy! The problem with `char buffer[100]` is that if the size of input string is more than 100, then your `cin >> buffer` would invoke **undefined behavior**, as it would attempt to write *beyond* the array. This problem can easily be avoided if you use `std::string`.

```
std::string input;
cin >> input; //this can read string of any unknown size!
cout << "length of input string : " << input.size()<< endl;
```

You can also use `input.length()` instead of `input.size()`. They return the same value.

Online Demo : http://www.ideone.com/Wdo31

Comment: @Downvoter: Please point out the problem with my answer, so that OP and I can know.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to (and quite possibly, can't).  Instead, use a `std::string` instead of a `char` buffer.